Add teletext subtitles to a ts container
ffmpeg has codec support, with dvbsub, to work with dvb and teletext subtitles in transport stream containers.
Starting with a .srt file of subtitles I can add these as a separate stream to a .ts file. I convert this .srt file to a VobSub format then add the subtitle .idx file like this:
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M ^
-i "input.ts" ^
-i "subtitles.idx" ^
-map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 dvbsub ^
OUTPUT.ts

But with this method the subtitles are not identified as teletext subtitles.
How do I add subtitles to a .ts file (for instance starting with a .srt file) so they are created as a stream of teletext subtitles as opposed to a stream of dvb subtitles?
Note to Mods:
My question is different from this question. I am asking how to add subtitles from a .srt file to a .ts container so they appear as a teletext subtitle stream. Whereas that question is asking how to copy a teletext subtitle stream from one .ts file to another. My question is not the same as that.
